# How to count frequency across column

Tags: r

How can I count the frequency across column?

```r
df <- data.frame(
  `Plant Code` = c(8, 5, 4, 6, 7, 5, 7, 8, 12, 8, 11, 6, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 9, 7, 5, 7, 7, 8),
  `Worker`     = c(5, 7, 8, 12, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5, 7, 7, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 1)
)

count(df,`Plant Code`)
count(df,`Worker`)
```

Comment: Did you try `table(df$\`Plant Code\` )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this?

```
> as.data.frame(xtabs(~Worker, df))
  Worker Freq
1      0    3
2      1    7
3      2    2
4      3    1
5      4    2
6      5    3
7      7    3
8      8    1
9     12    1
```

or

```
> as.data.frame(prop.table(xtabs(~Worker, df)))
  Worker       Freq
1      0 0.13043478
2      1 0.30434783
3      2 0.08695652
4      3 0.04347826
5      4 0.08695652
6      5 0.13043478
7      7 0.13043478
8      8 0.04347826
9     12 0.04347826
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the following solution from `janitor` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

# Counting the frequencies of `Worker` variable

df %>%
  tabyl(Worker)

 Worker n    percent
      0 3 0.13043478
      1 7 0.30434783
      2 2 0.08695652
      3 1 0.04347826
      4 2 0.08695652
      5 3 0.13043478
      7 3 0.13043478
      8 1 0.04347826
     12 1 0.04347826
```

Thanks to a timely hint from my dear friend @Anil Goyal, we can have a nicer output for our frequency table by limiting the number of `digits` to `2` while putting a `%` sign for each figure.

```
df %>%
  tabyl(Worker, Plant.Code) %>%
  adorn_percentages() %>%
  adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 2, affix_sign = TRUE)

 Worker     11     12      3       4      5       6       7      8      9
      0  0.00%  0.00%  0.00%   0.00% 66.67%   0.00%  33.33%  0.00%  0.00%
      1  0.00%  0.00%  0.00%  28.57% 14.29%  14.29%  14.29% 28.57%  0.00%
      2  0.00%  0.00%  0.00%   0.00% 50.00%   0.00%   0.00%  0.00% 50.00%
      3  0.00%  0.00%  0.00%   0.00%  0.00%   0.00% 100.00%  0.00%  0.00%
      4  0.00%  0.00% 50.00%   0.00%  0.00%   0.00%  50.00%  0.00%  0.00%
      5  0.00% 33.33%  0.00%   0.00%  0.00%   0.00%  33.33% 33.33%  0.00%
      7 33.33%  0.00%  0.00%   0.00% 33.33%   0.00%   0.00% 33.33%  0.00%
      8  0.00%  0.00%  0.00% 100.00%  0.00%   0.00%   0.00%  0.00%  0.00%
     12  0.00%  0.00%  0.00%   0.00%  0.00% 100.00%   0.00%  0.00%  0.00%
```

Comment: You may nicely format percentages in janitor also

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use `aggregate`. This gives you the count of worker per Plant.Code

```
aggregate(Worker ~ Plant.Code + Plant.Code, df, sum)
```

Output:

```
  Plant.Code Worker
1          3      4
2          4     10
3          5     10
4          6     13
5          7     13
6          8     14
7          9      2
8         11      7
9         12      5
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you are looking for. This is a summary table grouped by `Worker`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Worker) %>% 
  summarise(
    freq = n(),
    prop = 100 * freq / nrow(.),
    .groups="drop"
      )
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  Worker  freq  prop
*  <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1      0     3 13.0 
2      1     7 30.4 
3      2     2  8.70
4      3     1  4.35
5      4     2  8.70
6      5     3 13.0 
7      7     3 13.0 
8      8     1  4.35
9     12     1  4.35
```

If you want to table by `Plant Code`, just replace `Worker` in the `group_by`command accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Using `stack` with `proportions`

```
stack(proportions(table(df$Worker)))[2:1]
```

Comment: I just got to know there is a `proportions` from you :P, cheers!

Comment: It is just that `prop.table is an earlier name, retained for back-compatibility.` :-)

Comment: Great! New knowledge to me :)

Answer (score 0):

To do all columns:

```
sapply(df, table)
```